# Unclear question? please help

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

[This question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20476/human-body-control) is about human body control. I don't understand what was so ambiguous about it. Maybe if someone made it easier for me I could have explained it better.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

With the edit I find it relatively clear, but rather broad. It should be answerable though, at least as a loose list of processes that are under some form of conscious control. However, it would be useful if you defined more clearly exactly what you mean with "conscious control" (you can e.g. increase your pulse by hyperventilating, but this is quite different from deciding to raise your left arm). If you do not clarify this in your question, answers would most likely have to deal with these types of distinctions.

I'm voting to reopen, and we'll see what the community thinks and if there are any more clarifying comments.